# Hooking in to the email verificatin process

Tags: hooks, emails

In Drupal 7 (7.22), we'd like to hook into the email verification process for new users.  Perhaps the one time password node.  We need to do a test on the email address and set a value in a custom user field based on what we find.  This will allow us to give software activation terms to users with email matching certain business partner domains, for example.

Extra credit: we'd also like to enable a particular role for these users.  The first step, though, is to figure out where to hook in our php to do a regex test of $user->mail.

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to create a rule to activate on *After saving new user account*. You could do a Text comparison on `Account:mail` using your regular expression, and if the condition was TRUE, *Assign a role* for the  new user. It would be waiting for them when they verified their account.

If your requirements change for the site, it is easier to make an alteration through the UI than it is to track down the code that has to be changed.

The same rule can *Set a data value* in the custom user field if you wish.

EDIT:

Install and activate the [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) module. Then go to `/admin/config/workflow/rules` and create a new rule,  calling it, lets say 'Upgrade new user' and set it to react on *After saving a new user account*.

When the configuration screen comes up *Add condition* and select *Text comparison* (wait for the AJAX request to complete) then set the Data selector to `account:mail`. Under Matching Text, click the *Switch to direct input* button, enter your regular expression in the  Value box, and at the bottom use *Regular expression* for the Comparison operation. Then save the condition.

Then add two actions; First add *Add user role* (wait for the ajax to complete) and you should see `account` as your data selector. Then choose the role(s) to add and save the action.

Then add an action to *Set a data value*. In the Data selector, find your field, and click *Continue*. In the *Value* box using `<?php ... ?>` delimiters, enter the code you need to `return` your activation key.

Save everything and try it out.

Comment: That sounds like an excellent idea.  Now I just need to figure out how to create a rule. :)  I'm a little green in the Drupal 7 world.

Comment: First things first, I guess. Do I need both the Rules module and the Entity_API module for this?

Comment: Yes. Wait for me to finish :-)

Comment: Jeez...  hurry UP!!!   :)

Comment: I appreciate your help, btw.

Comment: You will notice the _wait for the ajax to complete_ comments. Rules does not play well if you are impatient and click the button to hurry things up. Good luck.

Comment: I got the custom field working with rules straight away.  The regex evaluation works correctly and we're pushing a value into the custom field correctly.  Thank you!  I'm still trying to get adding the role to work.  I'm miles ahead of where I was though.  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: The role is the easiest part. There are two input modes: Data selector and Direct input. Make sure that you are using a Data selector for the action, and it is `account`.

Comment: I have it working when changing an existing user to have a matching email address.  On a new user I get this failure: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4048-6' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {users_roles} (uid, rid) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 4048 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 6 ) in user_save() (line 603 of /home/.sites/111/site30/web/modules/user/user.module).

Comment: My guess is timing - perhaps the user isn't completely created when the rule fires.

Comment: Might be timing. Try a second rule that fires on the event _After updating an existing user account_ or try _User has logged in_. Use the same email condition, and make sure they have the role.

Comment: The _After updating an existing user account_ version is the one that works correctly... making me think it might be timing. I've added a 'sleep(10)' php action prior to setting the custom field and adding the role, but that didn't hep (or seemingly delay anything).

Comment: Then work with two rules. When the user first logs in and sets their password, the account is updated. Probably a good idea to set a second condition to test if the role is not there so the user object is not reloaded unneccessarily.